# What is more performant in SQL DELETE twice or DELETE with OR?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-delete

What is more performant in SQL `DELETE` twice or `DELETE` with `OR`?

In my case I have two options.

1

```
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps] WHERE [Code] IS NULL;

        DELETE FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps]
        WHERE [Id] IN (
            SELECT [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps] [Temp]
            JOIN (
                SELECT [Code], [Status], MAX([Id]) as [MaxId]
                FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps]
                GROUP BY [Code], [Status]
                HAVING COUNT([Id]) > 1
            ) [TempGroup]
            ON ([Temp].[Code] = [TempGroup].[Code] AND [Temp].[Status] = [TempGroup].[Status] AND [MaxId] != [Id])
        );
```

2

```
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps]
        WHERE ([Code] IS NULL) OR [Id] IN (
            SELECT [Id]
            FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps] [Temp]
            JOIN (
                SELECT [Code], [Status], MAX([Id]) as [MaxId]
                FROM [dbo].[LegalContractorTemps]
                GROUP BY [Code], [Status]
                HAVING COUNT([Id]) > 1
            ) [TempGroup]
            ON ([Temp].[Code] = [TempGroup].[Code] AND [Temp].[Status] = [TempGroup].[Status] AND [MaxId] != [Id])
        );
```

The `Code` and `Status` form a unique index in this case. I am using SQL Server.

Should I go with 1 or 2?

Comment: You did not specify which DB system you are using - it may make a difference. But you could let explain the database the cost for that queries (there is a way to get the execution plan of the statement - depends on your DB system)

Comment: @nabuchodonossor, could you, please, help me figure out what exactly I am using? I have the SQL Server installed and I am using the MSSMS. Is there a way to check what you are asking for in the MSSMS?

Comment: Sometimes it's better to split huge deletes into smaller batches anyway. How many rows are you deleting?

Comment: You might want to read [Eric Lippert's Which is Faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @hellouworld: I can not simple describe the way (to much of GUI), it´s acually a small Icon with 3 boxes and an arrow, so just google for "Display an Actual Execution Plan" and you will find the microsoft doc about that topic

Comment: Look at the query execution plans

Comment: It seems that I need to perform the research in my specific case taking into account all the variables which only I have access to (hardware, system, requirements, etc.). Should I remove the question then?

Comment: if you have an index on Code&Status then both approaches would execute in about the same time. If you do not have an index on Code (at least) then the two separate statements will require a table scan each and logically the two statements approach will be slower. `Code and Status form a unique index` ...however there is not a unique index defined on them, since your query tries to delete all nulls (code) and any duplicates (code&status) except the latest ones (except max(id)) ?